# Getting unexpected end on ruby

Tags: ruby

Trying to write a simple function that takes the highest difference and I keep getting the above error. I'm kinda new, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

Here's my code:

```
def stock_picker(arr)
  ##Declaration of Variables
  best_pair = []
  current_arr = arr.map(&:dup)
  got_best = false

  best_sum = 0;


  current_arr.each do |earnings|
    ##Slices new array starting from element to end
    temp_arr = current_arr.slice(current_arr.index(earnings)..-1)

    temp_arr.each do |more_earnings|
      i = 1
      until i == temp_arr.length do
        ##Subtracts current element with other elements
        temp_profit = temp_arr[i] - more_earnings
        p "Current profit is #{temp_profit}"
        ##Saves highest value
        if temp_profit > best_sum
          best_sum = temp_profit
        end
        i++
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Consider [`.each.with_index(1)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) instead of `.each` and  manually tracking your index with `i` -- you don't have to increment it yourself that way. For example, `temp_arr.each.with_index(1) { |value, index| ... }` (the `1` in this example sets your default index value to 1 instead of 0, the default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `++` operator does not exist in ruby. Go for `i += 1`

Comment: You may wish to elaborate the reason for the error The line `3++` followed by the line `1` returns `4`, so `3++` is treated as `3 +`. The method `Integer#+` does not find it's argument later in the line so it goes to the next where it finds `end`. Hence the exception, `SyntaxError ((irb):57: syntax error, unexpected end)`.

Answer (score 0):

- The unexpected end error is from i++. Change it to i+=1 to avoid that
  error.
- I'm assuming you want the highest difference returned, in    that
  case, put 'best_sum' before the last end.
- Another thing, i see you using `current_arr.index(earnings)`. This
  might cause problems when a number repeats itself. looping through
  the array with their index will solve this problem:
  `arr.each_with_index do |earnings,index|`